# URL in Ajax open()

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is my first Ajax program and I can't fix the code because I'm not sure where/what the problem is.

The error(which I'm unable to interpret) while using the debugger is, 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/function.txt. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

```
function calling()
{
    var x;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {

    x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    x.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("block").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }

    };
    x.open("GET", "http://localhost/function.txt",true);
    x.send();
}
```

function.txt

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h2>Ajax is working</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: localhost have a server who listening to port 80 ? If you have one, this server accept CORS request ?

Comment: People here gave you excelent answers, you should upvote and pick one as best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is your js located at the same location as your function.txt?

For more information about CORS, have a look at this link: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

**UPDATE:**
This works for me, I think there is maybe something with your Apache settings...

```
function calling()
{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      method = "GET",
      url = "function.txt";

  xhr.open(method, url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
              alert(xhr.responseText);
          }
      };
  xhr.send();
}

calling();
```

Comment: Yes, my js, html and .txt files are at the same location

Comment: This is the error I get after changing the URL: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Apache%20Tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M18/webapps/jsp/function.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make Ajax calls to a url from a different domain if said domain does not explicitly allow it (via 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header).
Your error means that you're making your Ajax call from another domain. If your function.txt file is located at the same location as your js, try using relative path in your `.open()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting a CORS request, which is unsafe and is prohibited by browsers by default. If you are in control of the target site, you can [enable CORS](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled). If that's not the case, then you will need to write a page which will be used as a proxy, that is, you will send the request to this page instead of the target site's page. The page, on its turn will send the request to the target page and send the output to the browser. While this is a workable solution you will need to make sure that all the absolute paths of the target site are handled well.